# Am I being underpaid by my employer based on my contract?

Tags: calculation

I have a full time contract for $43.90 per hour, which was calculated to $91,300 annual salary. I am paid twice a month. We work a 9/80 shift, which means 9 hour days so we can have every other Friday off. When I look at my pay stub, the amount I am being paid divided by the number of hours shows a consistent $41.80 per hour. This is true for all categories, such as regular time and holiday pay, as well as recent bereavement hours. I am told the calculation for annual salary is based on 2080 hours. Am I being under paid by my employer?

Comment: Are you exempt (on a salary) or non-exempt (paid overtime). When you were hired, was it with a stated annual salary? or was it with an hourly rate? And per-chance is it $41.08 (not $41.80) on your paycheck?

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: Also: is the amount you’re paid $3804.16 (gross) or something less?

Comment: If you're working 9-hour days, for 9 out of 10 days (2 weeks), then you're working 9/81, not 9/80 and your employer is probably getting a free hour from you every 2 weeks.

Comment: My experience with 9/80 schedules is that it's 9 hour days Mon-Thurs.  Fridays alternate between 0 hours and 8 hours (this gets you 9/80 instead of 9/81).  Holiday weeks can be weird depending on if your employer is paying 8 or 9 hours for a holiday.

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to what your contract says. If it states you should be paid $43.90/hr, then that is what you should expect to see on your pay stubs. If the hourly rate was agreed to, and the gross amount is not equal to the number of hours * $43.90 before any subtractions, then it's likely an error was made. In that case I would contact the HR or AP department for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some missing information because 2080 hours divided by 81 hours per 2 weeks is 25.68 pay periods.  Therefore, some days are unaccounted for (unpaid holidays, alternate universe employer calendar, user error, whatever).

Rather than ask us to guess if you are being underpaid by your empoyer, you should speak to your employer and get clarification.

Comment: OP didn't say pay is bi-weekly, OP said twice monthly, so, there may only be 24 pay periods.

Comment: The  OP said  9 hour days with every other Friday off.  From that I assume that means  81 work hours per two week period.  Do the math from there and you'll see that it doesn't add up to 52 weeks, hence the missing days.  How they pay him (once per month) is merely a redistribution of the hours across months of different length. If it's not 81 work hours per 2 weeks then ignore what I have written.

Comment: If doing it that way doesn't compute for you then try this.  There are 261 weekdays this year. If OP was paid for  9 out of 10 of them  (some holidays) then that's 234.9 days worked.  At $43.90 per 9 hour day then he should be paid $92,809. Since he stated that he is due an annual salary of $91,300 then it's still the same answer - something is unaccounted for.  Throw out the odd day and it's exactly 26 two week periods which would mean exactly 234 days worked or a salary of $92.453.  Still means that some data is missing.  He should speak to his employer.

Comment: 2080*43.9 is 91,312. He is being paid twice a month. Every pay stub is different in total, but gives 41.8... They are working 81 hrs per fortnight instead of 80. Total hrs workable is 261 days, 2088 plus 26 hrs , one hr additional every 2 weeks. But this is not adding up. For 41.8, the working days are taken as 270.